# ExtJS 4: Understanding hasMany and belongsTo

Tags: model, extjs4, has-many, extjs4.2, belongs-to

I've been struggling to understand how to use hasMany and belongsTo for quite sometime. My understanding is hasMany is a 1:many relationship and belongsTo is a many:1 relationship--**aside:** so does that imply that if you have a hasMany relationship, a belongsTo is needed in its child model?  I've read several articles on it:

- Loading Nested Data on the [Ext.data.reader.Reader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader) page.
- [Ext.data.association.BelongsTo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.BelongsTo)
- [Ext.data.association.HasMany](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany)
- [Association Sample in extjs 4.2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482819/association-sample-in-extjs-4-2)
- [ExtJS Tutorials - HasMany article](http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/05/extjs-hasmany-relationships-rules.html)
- [ExtJS Tutorials - BelongsTo article](http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/05/extjs-belongsto-association-rules.html)
- [hasMany vs belongsTo](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152731/what-is-the-main-difference-between-has-many-and-belongs-to-relationship-in-mysq)
- [ExtJS 4: Models with Associations and Stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622878/extjs-4-models-with-associations-and-stores)

Still a bit confused though. Let's say I have the following data:

```
var data = {
  "config": {
    "name": "blah",
    "id": 1,
    "someconfig": [{
        "name": "Services", "tabs": [{
            "id": 0, "name": "Details", "layout": "hbox"
          }, {
            "id": 1, "name": "Sources", "layout": "hbox"
          }, {
            "id": 2, "name": "Paths", "layout": "hbox"
          }, {
            "id": 3, "name": "Ports", "layout": "hbox"
          }, {
            "id": 4, "name": "Levels", "layout": "hbox"
          }, {
            "id": 5, "name": "Notes", "layout": "hbox"
          }]
      }, {
        "name": "Services2", "tabs": [{}]
      }]
  }
};
```

I would create a model for config:

```
Ext.define('Config', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['name'],
  hasMany: [{
    name: 'someconfig',
    model: 'Someconfig',
    associationKey: 'someconfig'
  }],
  proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    data: data,
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'config'
    }
  }
});
```

So Config can have many Someconfigs because in the data, someconfig is an array of objects. Here's the Someconfig model:

```
Ext.define('Someconfig', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    'name'
  ],
  hasMany: [{
    name: 'tabs',
    model: 'Tabs',
    associationKey: 'tabs'
  }]
});
```

Ok, same deal. Someconfig can have many Tabs because in the data, tabs is an array of objects. Here's the Tabs model:

```
Ext.define('Tabs', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    'id',
    'name',
    'layout'
  ],
  belongsTo: [{
    name: 'tabs',
    model: 'Someconfig',
    associationKey: 'tabs'
  }]
});
```

Now, belongsTo is in there because I was messing around with this property.  Regardless, I can't access Tabs from Someconfig, but I can access Someconfig from Config. Take a look at this code:

```
Config.load(1, {
  success: function(record, operation) {
    console.log(record.get('name'));  // works
    console.log(record.someconfig().getCount());  // works, gives me 2
    console.log(record.someconfig().data.items[0].data);  // only prints out name and config_id
//      console.log(record.someconfig().tabs());  // doesn't exist
  }
});
```

**jsFiddle**: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/incutonez/3q3uL/)

What I want to know is, shouldn't I be able to access **tabs()** from **someconfig()**, or am I misunderstanding the relationships? If it's the former, how would I fix my code?

Cross-posted from [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?274593-Understanding-hasMany-and-belongsTo.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your approach here:

1. When you call the **getter** for a **one-to-many** relationship, you are actually retrieving a reference to a **Store object** that contains a set of related objects, so attempting to retrieve the relationship **tabs** for the store makes no sense.
2. You must **retrieve one element** from the relationship store, and then **get its related tabs** by **calling** the **tabs method** that will return a Store Object containing a set of tabs for that specific instance.
3. If you want **to access** to any of the **related tabs** you must again **select a single object** from that store, to transverse the whole relationship tree you should do something like this:

> ```
> someconfig = record.someconfig().getAt(0);
> sometab = someconfig.tabs().getAt(0);
> ```

Here's a [modified version of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/xPn6t/) that works. 
Hope it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Yup.  You're exactly right, and those are the conclusions I came to yesterday after playing around with it some more.  Thanks!

Comment: So what's interesting about this is, `someconfig` does not show in the data of `record`... I can only access `someconfig` by calling its method.  This does not make sense to me... if the `config` model hasMany `someconfig`, it should show up in `config` as an array of models!